# How to remove all emojis from excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql, utf-8

I have an excel sheet that I want to export to MySQL using the "MySQL for Excel" feature. However I'm having trouble getting that to work because some of the cells have emojis such as  in it. And so I can't convert those cells to be of datatype text for MySQL. I tried using CLEAN() but it doesn't get rid of them.

Is there a way to filter out these emojis?

If there are other alternatives or work around that would allow me to export the excel data to MySQL I'm open to that as well. Thank you.

Comment: You probably need to set encoding for your MySQL database to UTF-8 rather than cleaning the data.

Comment: That would be `utf8mb4` in MySQL (not just utf8), because historical reasons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your emojis are Shapes, then within Excel, using *VBA*, run this simple macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim sh As Shape

    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            sh.Delete
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If the emojis are *Text*, then select a cell and:

```
Sub kleanIt()
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant, L As Long
    Dim CH As String, i As Long, N As Long

    Set r = ActiveCell
    v = r.Value
    L = Len(v)

    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
        N = AscW(CH)
        If N < 1 Or N > 256 Then
            v = Replace(v, CH, "")
        End If
    Next i

    r.Value = v
End Sub
```

Comment: But they're technically text, not Shapes...

Comment: @grawity  If the are text, then all you need is the unicode value *(either decimal or hex)* for each emoji to remove it by **Find/Replace**

Comment: @grawity  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It was text. The code works, thank you!

Comment: @Alice  You are quite welcome!